# How to add grandtotal of a column in pandas pivot table dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Need to add total of a column in a pivot table dataframe

I have a pivot table dataframe  and need to add a sub-column which is a total of **Bill2**

`data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)`
   
 `data_frame1 = data_frame1.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)`
    
`tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a!= 'All' else (a,b) for a,b in data_frame1.columns]`
   
 `data_frame1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)`

**output:**

```
              OCT-19             Nov-19        Dec-19
             Bill1 Bill2      Bill1 Bill2     Bill1 Bill2      
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS   1     1         1         1       1        1
```

**desired Output:**

```
               OCT-19             Nov-19            Dec-19
              Bill1  Bill2     Bill1 Bill2    Bill1 Bill2  FY19-Total   
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind   OS    1      1          1     1        1    1       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select MultiIndex by `xs` and `sum`, output assign to tuple for `MultiIndex`:

```
df[('','total')] = df.xs('Bill2', axis=1, level=1).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
         Sep-19       Oct-19       Nov-19            
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2 total
A Ind OS      1     1      1     1      1     4     6
```

For filter by some years, e.g. only `2019` is necessary filter by mask before:

```
print (df)
         Sep-20       Oct-19       Nov-19      
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2
A Ind OS      1     1      1     7      1     4

#convert first level for datetimes and then to years
level0 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.get_level_values(0), format='%b-%y').year
print (level0)
Int64Index([2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019], dtype='int64')

mask = level0 == 2019
df[('','total2019')] = df.loc[:, mask].xs('Bill2', axis=1, level=1).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
         Sep-20       Oct-19       Nov-19                
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2 total2019
A Ind OS      1     1      1     7      1     4        11
```

EDIT:

For correct sorting after append new sum row is necessary working with datetimes (or periods), soluion is:

```
print (df)
         Nov-19       Dec-19       Jan-20      
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2
A Ind OS      1  1.28      1  1.28      1  1.28

level0 = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.get_level_values(0), format='%b-%y')
level1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1)
print (level0)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01', '2019-11-01', '2019-12-01', '2019-12-01',
               '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

df.columns = [level0, level1]

mask = level0.year == 2019
df[(pd.to_datetime('2019-12-01'),'total2019')] = df.loc[:, mask].xs('Bill2', axis=1, level=1).sum(axis=1)
df = df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1)
print (df)
         2019-11-01       2019-12-01                 2020-01-01      
              Bill1 Bill2      Bill1 Bill2 total2019      Bill1 Bill2
A Ind OS          1  1.28          1  1.28      2.56          1  1.28
```

Last if need original format of datetimes:

```
level0 = df.columns.get_level_values(0).strftime('%b-%y')
level1 = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

df.columns = [level0, level1]
print (df)
         Nov-19       Dec-19                 Jan-20      
          Bill1 Bill2  Bill1 Bill2 total2019  Bill1 Bill2
A Ind OS      1  1.28      1  1.28      2.56      1  1.28
```

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - So need sum only `19` years?

Comment: 19 & 20 years but the 19TOTAL should come in **DEC-19** and 20TOTAL should come in **DEC-20**

Comment: bro how to make the **total** to come after Dec-19...
can i use `df[('Dec-19','Total2019')] = df.loc[:, mask].xs('Bill2', axis=1, level=1).sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - yes and no. Problem is column name is super `('Dec-19','Total2019')`, but it always add to end :(

Comment: And if sorting it, get bad sort.

Comment: any idea how to insert the **Fullyear total** column at the end of Dec-19?